# when I run my application I face this problem

Tags: android, flutter

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseAidl'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\admob_flutter-1.0.1\android\local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s

Exception: The plugin admob_flutter could not be built due to the issue above.

> 

Comment: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\admob_flutter-1.0.1\android\local.properties
try to delete local.properties file and compile again

Answer (score 0):

I too solved the issue by upgrading build gradle version.

previous setting in build.gradle file of project was:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0")
```

current setting:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
```

The issue was gone immediately. :)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}
```